# How to expose `engine_createBlock` manual-seal RPC?

Tags: rpc

Right now when I run:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":"1", "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "rpc_methods", "params":[]}' http://localhost:9933
```

I get that `engine_createBlock` is not an RPC method. How do I expose it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details here? Where are you expecting `engine_createBlock` to come from?

Answer (score 3):

Some RPCs are [*not safe* to expose](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/custom-rpcs/#public-rpcs) for anyone to call, this is an example of one.

Why? creating and attempting to publish a block that is invalid could lead to [slashing](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-staking#slashing). Thus you wouldn't want anyone to be able to instruct your node to build a block.

Here are a few flags you might put to use to access `engine_createBlock`, and you can see more in `--help` used with the node:

```
        --rpc-external
            Listen to all RPC interfaces.
            
            Default is local. Note: not all RPC methods are safe to be exposed publicly. Use an RPC
            proxy server to filter out dangerous methods. More details:
            <https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/custom-rpcs/#public-rpcs>. Use `--unsafe-rpc-
            external` to suppress the warning if you understand the risks.


        --rpc-methods <METHOD SET>
            RPC methods to expose.
            
            - `Unsafe`: Exposes every RPC method.
            - `Safe`: Exposes only a safe subset of RPC methods, denying unsafe RPC methods.
            - `Auto`: Acts as `Safe` if RPC is served externally, e.g. when `--{rpc,ws}-external` is
              passed, otherwise acts as `Unsafe`.
            
            [default: Auto]
            [possible values: Auto, Safe, Unsafe]
```